# ros: how to track changes in agents movement

Tags: ros

I'm a noob in this matter so this question might be a bit dumb but I'm trying to launch a multi agent world file where each agent need to know wHo is closest to it.

What I have by now: multi agent system where each agent has a laser sensor and they all move randomly and change direction when they are close to an obstacle which can be another agent or a wall defined in the world file

I'm trying to find a way not just to realize when I hit an obstacle but also to know if it is a moving one and if so where is it moving and how fast.

Thanks guys for any suggestion

Comment: This is a very broad question and I guess there are lots of possible ways to solve this problem. Basically you have to track the obstacles and see how their position changes (I guess there should be lots of work available on object tracking in laser scans). To do so, an agent also needs to know its own movement, so some kind localization is necessary. Assuming that no map of the environment is given at the beginning, this problem is known as "SLAM" (simultaneous localization and mapping) and there are lots of approaches to solve it.

Comment: OK. I now see I omitted too many details: 
first, I do have a map, but the agents within are changing locations constantly
I know my movement, because I publish and subscribe for location and laser scanner

I can know at any given time where every other agent is - using my laser scanner subscriber, but is there a neat way to save all data so I could figure out where every agent is

Comment: I think, the answer is still too broad to give a complete answer here. But as I said, tracking objects in laser scans should be a well studied problem. Take a look [here](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&q=object+tracking+in+laser+scans&btnG=&lr=) maybe some of the papers can help you.